# Из RecyclerView Adapter сделать ViewPager Adapter

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Помогите сделать `adapter` для `ViewPager` из `adapter` `RecyclerView`.
Спасибо!

```
public class HomeAdapterParse extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapterParse.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<BannerItem> parseItems;
private Context context;

public HomeAdapterParse(ArrayList<BannerItem> parseItems, Context context) {
    this.parseItems = parseItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HomeAdapterParse.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.baner_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeAdapterParse.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    BannerItem parseItem = parseItems.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(parseItem.getTitle());
    Picasso.get().load(parseItem.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return parseItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        BannerItem parseItem = parseItems.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BanerDetali.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", parseItem.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("image", parseItem.getImage());
        intent.putExtra("detailUrl", parseItem.getDetailUrl());
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
}

public void setFilter (ArrayList<BannerItem> newList) {
    parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
    parseItems.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну в целом адаптер для ViewPage , да и сам ViewPage оформляется несколько иначе (совсем иначе.)
Предлагаю вам озанкомиться с данным материалом, мейби этот метод вам поможет : https://habr.com/ru/company/surfstudio/blog/461873/